# What are the initial estimates taken in Logistic regression in Scikit-learn for the first iteration?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying out logistic regression from scratch in python.(through finding probability estimates,cost function,applying gradient descent for increasing the maximum likelihood).But I have a confusion regarding which estimates should I take for the first iteration process.I took all the estimates as 0(including the intercept).But the results are different from that we get in Scikit-learn.I want to know which are the initial estimates taken in Scikit-learn for logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

First of all scikit learn's LogsiticRegerssion uses **regularization**. So unless you apply that too , it is unlikely you will get exactly the same estimates. if you really want to test your method versus scikit's , it is better to use their gradient decent implementation of Logistic regersion which is called [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) . Make certain you put `loss='log'` for logistic regression and set `alpha=0` to remove regularization, but again you will need to adjust the `iterations` and `eta` as their implementation is likely to be slightly different than yours.

To answer specifically about the initial estimates, I don't think it matters, but most commonly you set everything to 0 (including the intercept) and should converge just fine.

Also bear in mind GD (gradient Decent) models are hard to tune sometimes and you may need to apply some scaling(like [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)) to your data beforehand as very high values are very likely to drive your gradient out of its slope. Scikit's implementation adjusts for that.